# Eye of Gnome (EOG) - Modify Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to change the default shortcuts of the image viewer Eye of Gnome?

I would like to remap a few shortcuts, like the spacebar and mouse thumb buttons.
As far as I can tell, the application does not offer the modification of shortcuts. Also, I neither could find anything useful in the help document nor with Google.
Maybe there is a way by means of a configuration file anywhere.
I use Eye of Gnome on Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon.

Comment: You should be able to alter shortcuts by editing `~/.config/eog/accels` or, for older `eog` versions, `~/.gnome2/accels/eog`. Basically you edit the accel line corresponding to a particular action and replace keys/key combos as per your taste, then uncomment it (remove the semicolon) and save the file.

Comment: @don_crissti Unfortunately, in `~/.config/eog/` there is only the file `eog_toolbar.xml`. Under the second path there is also no eog file. But thanks anyway, now I have a better idea of what to look for and how to edit it.

Comment: Here's an [`accels` sample file](https://github.com/iflowfor8hours/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/eog/accels), HTH.